# FullContact API ajax request using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
var person = "";
var fullcAPIkey = "my_private_api_key"

$("#create").on("click", function() {

  person = $("#email").val();

  $.ajax({        
    url:"https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/person.json?email=" + person + "&apikey=" + fullcAPIkey,
    method: "GET"       
  }).done(function(response) {
      console.log(response); 
  });    
});
```

I'm getting error 403 (forbidden). I feel that I've placed something wrong in the url request. #create points to the submit button. Thank you.

Comment: What does `$('#email').val()` show you in one of your test cases? Ostensibly it's an email, but it's good to verify that first.

Comment: you should not show us your API Key. I'M pretty sure it against the rules of fullcontact.

Comment: Also, for sanity's sake, try with `apikey` as `apiKey`, since that's the type case they use in their docs :) (like I said, shouldn't matter w/ query parameters, but good to try it anyway)

Comment: Last but not least in our debugging 101, try setting the `X-FullContact-APIKey` (as their docs also suggest) instead of the query param, and see if you get the same response.

Comment: @JoshBeam tested it. You're right. That's the solution! It's case sensitive

Comment: @JoshuaK muahaha. Thanks for testing. It's always something little like that...

Comment: Tip - change your API key. It's still visible in the edit history of this question!

Comment: @JoshuaK could I see your solution please? I've tried changing "&apikey" to "&APIKey", "&apiKey", and "&X-FullContact-myprivateAPIkey" to no avail.

Comment: `&apiKey` is correct. And it works! Call the URL directly with a browser and take a look at the response. With `&apikey` it returns a message that the api key is not valid. `&apiKey` returns a message that differs from that.